# What is the efficient way to show images in a Webview on android 10 and above?

Tags: android, webview, android-10.0

I was using a webview to print some images and text details in andorid. But on android 10 and above it is not possible to display images with file location in webview (Even though am trying to access images from app cache which usually doesn't require the storage permission), so i have to display images with imgageBase64. But which causes OutOfMemoryError when i try to print very large images.

Is there any options to achieve it?

The code am using is given below.

```
private void createWebPrintJob(WebView webView) {

       
        PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) ReadNote.this
                .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

        String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + "_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".pdf";

       
        PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter(jobName);

       
        printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,
                new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());

       
    }


private void doWebViewPrint() {
        // Create a WebView object specifically for printing
        WebView webView = new WebView(ReadNote.this);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                createWebPrintJob(view);
                mWebView = null;
            }
        });
String htmlimages="";
for (int i=0;i<cacheimagenames.size();++i){
htmlimages=htmlimages+"<img src=\""+ Uri.fromFile(new File(ReadNote.this.getApplication().getCacheDir(),"/images/"+cacheimagenames.get(i))) + "\"><br><br>";
}

String htmlDocument = "<html><body>\n" + htmlimages + "<\body><\html>\n"

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlDocument, "text/HTML", "UTF-8", null);

        mWebView = webView;

}
```

Comment: Why not just request the storage permission and there your problem is solved? You can make it only request the permission for the android devices using android 10 or above. Id also suggesting using a library to make it even easier https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter

Comment: It won't work with the permission, i tried that too. (App cache access usually doesn't need permission though). Showing image in webview is hectic.

Comment: Whats the error ?

Comment: When i use file uri to display image, it just show the system thumbnail of image not loaded (only on android10 and above other lower versions shows it without any trouble). That is why i used bitmap to imgageBase64 but that causes outofmemory error.